# Filtering using "grep" and "tail" to search patterns line for line

Tags: linux, bash, grep, tail

Goal: Needing to use `tail` with `grep` search each incoming line for a specific pattern, provided by a `while` loop

Issue:  Despite the proper syntax/placement of the `grep` command no incoming lines are being filtered and checked for the pattern

```
function interval () 
{ 
        echo $(date '+%y%m%d %H%M%S') $cnt 
        cnt=0 
} 

declare -i cnt=0 
trap interval SIGUSR1

shopt -s lastpipe 

tail -f --pid=$$ ${1:-access.log} | grep "20051" | while read aline 
do 
        let cnt++ 
done
```

Comment: The best way to ask these questions is to provide sample input and desired output and what you have tried.  Also, be open to other options as your implementation may not be the best and/or most efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to other options, you might want to take a look at this. Using the watch command could be very useful in this case. Redirecting all your output into a file, say file.txt,

`watch -d cat file.txt | grep "20051"`

Taking a look at the watch command man page, you can customize the time interval between consecutive executions.